# Error: invalid syntax python

Tags: python

Boa Noite Pessoal sou iniciante em Python.Ai quando rodor o codigo aparecer o 
if ano==0:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

t=input('Digite o Nome do Filme:')
ano=int(input('Digite o Ano do Filme:')

if ano==0:
 req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'&language=pt-BR')) 
 bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml') 
 print(bs.find_all('img')) 
else:
 req=requests.get(req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'%20y%3A'+str(ano)+'&language=pt-BR'))) 
 bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml') 
 print(bs.find_all('img'))
```

Fiz as Alteraçoes Continuar o mesmo Erro.

Comment: Use: str(ano) na concatenação. Troque  req=requests.get(str('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'%20y%3A'+ano+'&language=pt-BR')) por  req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'%20y%3A'+str(ano)+'&language=pt-BR')

Comment: deu erro if ano==0:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JacksuelSoaresBraga eu reverti a pergunta porque o formato site não comporta que alterações que invalidem as respostas sejam feitas. Pois mesmo o AR(Autor da Resposta) se esforçando para resolver o seu problema, se você modifica a pergunta o AR corre o risco de ser negativado mesmo resolvendo parte de seu problema. Use os comentários abaixo das respostas para pedir esclarecimentos e atualizaçÕes das respostas. Qualquer dúvida faça o nosso [tour]. Se precisar faça uma nova pergunta, [ask], e se precisar coloque para essa pergunta como referência.

Answer (score 1):

Jacksuel,

Na linha que você requisita o ano, falta fechar um parênteses:

```
ano=int(input('Digite o Ano do Filme:'))
```

Depois no get do seu if de ano igual a zero, você fechou dois parênteses, precisa remover um:

```
req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'&language=pt-BR')
```

Por fim, no get do seu else, você novamente fechou um parênteses a mais, precisa remover um aqui também, porém além desse erro de sintaxe, você também escreveu duas vezes o `req=request.get`, inclusive um dentro do outro, corrija da seguinte forma:

```
req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'%20y%3A'+str(ano)+'&language=pt-BR')
```

---

Corrigindo todos esses pontos, seu código deve ficar mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

t=input('Digite o Nome do Filme:')
ano=int(input('Digite o Ano do Filme:'))

if ano==1:
  req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'&language=pt-BR')
  bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml') 
  print(bs.find_all('img')) 
else:
  req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'%20y%3A'+str(ano)+'&language=pt-BR')
  bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml') 
  print(bs.find_all('img'))
```

> Tome cuidado com os espaços em Python, quando você corrigiu os erros que mencionei você deu um espaço antes do IF, isso também vai gerar exceções.

Comment: Agora mudou o erro para IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Sim, pela sua edição você quebrou a indentação do código quando efetuou as correções.

Comment: Jacksuel, fiz uma edição nas informações, tome cuidado com os espaços e tabulações no Python.

Comment: recomendar alguma videoaula um documento que explicar?

Comment: Opa, cara, nunca fiz os cursos dele, mas ouço fala SUPER bem, e tem aulas de Python: https://www.youtube.com/user/cursosemvideo